# Codeigniter - Problema na instalação da biblioteca phpdotenv (.env - para variáveis de ambiente)

Tags: codeigniter-3

Estou tentando instalar o phpdotenv no Codeigniter 3, seguindo estas instruções:

[Variáveis de Ambiente no Codeigniter](http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/como-ler-variaveis-de-ambiente-no-codeigniter/)

Mas, está dando o seguinte problema:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Dotenv\Loader, string given, called in
>   /application/config/hooks.php on line 5 and defined
>
> Filename: src/Dotenv.php
>
> Line Number: 31

O meu arquivo /application/config/hooks.php está configurado da mesma forma que indicado no tutorial:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$hook['pre_system'] = function() {
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APPPATH);
    $dotenv->load();
};
```

Eu já pesquisei, mas ainda não encontrei a solução.
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer a instalação do phpdotenv de uma forma diferente das instruções do primeiro tutorial.
Neste tutorial a instalação é feita sem o uso do Composer.

[PHPDotEnv para CodeIgniter (sem o uso do Composer)](https://github.com/agungjk/phpdotenv-for-codeigniter)